# objective-c NSFilePosixPermissions to human readable NSString

Tags: objective-c, permissions, nsstring, posix, human-readable

is there a way to get human readable string (@"drwxr-xr-x" for example) from an NSFilePosixPermissions integer ?

Comment: Nope. Completely impossible without the Unicorn Talisman and a whole lot of liquor. (See Bitwise Operations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Comment: (Up-voted the question since it's a good one and I'm being a smart-a**.) :-)

Comment: Thanks Joshua! the accepted answer seems to be fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file system permissions attribute is simply an unsigned long value. The code below could obviously be made more efficient but it shows [more or less] what needs to be done to get the string you want:

```
// The indices of the items in the permsArray correspond to the POSIX
// permissions. Essentially each bit of the POSIX permissions represents
// a read, write, or execute bit.
NSArray *permsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"---", @"--x", @"-w-", @"-wx", @"r--", @"r-x", @"rw-", @"rwx", nil];
NSFileManager *fm = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
NSDictionary *attrs = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:@"some/path.txt" error:NULL];

if (!attrs)
    return nil;

NSUInteger perms = [attrs filePosixPermissions];

if ([[attrs fileType] isEqualToString:NSFileTypeDirectory])
    [result appendString:@"d"];
else
    [result appendString:@"-"];

// loop through POSIX permissions, starting at user, then group, then other.
for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // this creates an index from 0 to 7
    unsigned long thisPart = (perms >> (i * 3)) & 0x7;

    // we look up this index in our permissions array and append it.
    [result appendString:[permsArray objectAtIndex:thisPart]];
}

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you can create an array like so:

```
NSArray *convertToAlpha = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"---",@"--x",@"-w-",@"--wx",@"r--",@"r-x",@"rw-",@"rwx", nil];
```

Then after tranlating the NSFilePosixPermissions to octal, split the resulting number into its componenet digits and use convertToAlpha  to map each digit to its alphanumeric representation....

Comment: xm... I'll try that. I'll get back if I make it, to post the entire solution. Thank you!

Comment: @VassilisGr, @ennuikiller: beware though, you need an `@` symbol behind each string, and also need to add `nil` to your list of arguments.