# how to convert NSNumber into NSString rwx type

Tags: ios, unix, permissions, nsstring, nsnumber

i'm new in unix permission and chmod.

In my IOS app, i try to get a file permission value from SFTP server. The value i've got is in a NSNumber value and the value is 19455. I want to convert it into NSString in rwx (read, write, execute) value, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[objective-c NSFilePosixPermissions to human readable NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127147/objective-c-nsfileposixpermissions-to-human-readable-nsstring)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i have another question here, can you tell me what the meaning of that 5 digits permission value? because i was now that is 4 type users for permission, there are user, group, all, and other, what is the 5th?